# How can I add multiple dimensions in AWS Lambda Python 2.7

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

**I have this code for adding new metric in cloudwatch alarm and I want to add one more dimension 'Name': 'FileSystem', 'Value': '/dev/xvda1'**

```
*MetricName='DiskSpaceUtilization', Namespace='System/Linux',    Statistic='Average', Dimensions=[ { 'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value':   instance['InstanceId'] }, ],*
```

========================================================================

Basically I want this through Lambda
[It should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfszU.png)
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give the full function that is being used? Are you using boto?

Comment: AlarmDescription='DISK path reaches more than 75%',
                ActionsEnabled=True,
                AlarmActions=[
                    ec2_sns,
                ],
                MetricName='DiskSpaceUtilization',
                Namespace='System/Linux',
                Statistic='Average',
                Dimensions=[
                    {   
                        'Name': 'InstanceId',
                        'Value': instance['InstanceId']
                    },
                    
                ],"

Comment: Yes I am using boto and I am able to add one dimension which is "InstanceID" , I want to add one more LinuxSystem

Comment: This doesn't appear to be specific to Lambda. It is just a general Boto + CloudWatch question. I would remove Lambda from the title and tag (you used the wrong Lambda tag anyway), and replace them with CloudWatch.